# How do I prove the function below surjective?

Tags: functions

$f: \mathbb{Q} \to A$, where $A$ is the multiplicative group of all complex numbers with finite order, defined by $f(a)=exp(-2 \pi i a)$.

Say $z\in A$ such that $z^n=1$. $\implies r e^{i \theta} =1$. Then $e^{i\theta}=1/r$. What do I do next?

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean by  '"finite order " ?

Comment: @Nizar I assume that it means finite order in the group $(\mathbb C^*,\cdot)$. Without fancy words, $x\in\mathbb C$ has finite order if (and only if) there exists a positive integer such that $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $z \in A$: this means that a natural number $n$ such that $z^n=1$ exists. First of all, you should observe that since $z^n=|z|^ne^{i \text{arg}(z)\cdot n}=1$, every complex number with finite order lies on the unit circle $\mathbb{S}$, i.e. $|z|=1$.

Let's show that every complex number of this form can be written as $e^{-2\pi ia}$ for some rational number $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Let $w=e^{i \theta}\in A$. Without loss of generality, we claim that $0\leq \theta< 2\pi$. Since $w \in A$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $e^{in\theta}=1=e^{-2ki\pi }$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$. For this equality to hold, the exponents must be equal, since we restricted $\theta$'s range to $[0,2\pi)$:

$$in\theta=-2ki\pi \iff \theta=-2\pi i\left (\frac{k}{n} \right )=-2\pi i a$$

Since $k,n$ are natural numbers, $a\in \mathbb{Q}$.